# Do you know why "flutter run" is failing?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I have a flutter project that needed iOS support, but when I am trying to run the project in an iPhone 12 Pro Max Simulator, it is throwing this error in the Android Studio console.

`Running pod install...                                              3.3s
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `facebook_event` from `.symlinks/plugins/facebook_event/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `file_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/file_picker/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.11.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.11.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_crashlytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios`
firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.11.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.11.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_facebook_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_inappwebview` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_inappwebview/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_local_notifications` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_local_notifications/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `geocoder` from `.symlinks/plugins/geocoder/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `geolocation` from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocation/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `image_cropper` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_cropper/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `open_file` from `.symlinks/plugins/open_file/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `package_info_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/package_info_plus/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `permission_handler` from `.symlinks/plugins/permission_handler/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `rate_my_app` from `.symlinks/plugins/rate_my_app/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `share_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/share_plus/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_ios/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `sms_consent` from `.symlinks/plugins/sms_consent/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `streams_channel` from `.symlinks/plugins/streams_channel/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_9_b_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/b/5/FBSDKCoreKit/13.1.0/FBSDKCoreKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_1_6_1.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/1.0.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/1.0.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/1.0.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/1.0.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/1.1.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.0.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.1.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.2.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.3.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.3.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.3.5/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.3.6/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.3.7/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.4.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.4.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.4.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/2.4.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.5/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.6/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.7/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.8/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.9/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.10/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.0.11/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.1.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.1.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.1.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.1.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.2.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.2.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.3.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.3.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.3.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.3.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.3.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.3.5/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.4.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.4.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.4.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.5/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.6/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.5.7/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.6.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.6.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.6.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.8.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/3.8.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.0-beta/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.0-beta2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.0.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.4/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.5/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.6/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.1.7/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.2.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.2.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.2.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.0/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.1/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.3/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.14.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_8_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/8/6/OrderedSet/5.0.0/OrderedSet.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_4_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/6.1.0/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_7_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/7/4/TOCropViewController/2.6.1/TOCropViewController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in
  repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_b_3_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/b/3/c/FBSDKLoginKit/13.1.0/FBSDKLoginKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_b_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.14.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/8.11.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_8_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo
  update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo
  update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo
  update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_3_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/3/c/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/8.14.0/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
  perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/b/5/FBSDKCoreKit/8.2.0/FBSDKCoreKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/b/5/FBSDKCoreKit/8.2.0/FBSDKCoreKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/b/5/FBSDKCoreKit/8.2.0/FBSDKCoreKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/b/5/FBSDKCoreKit/12.1.0/FBSDKCoreKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKCoreKit":
  In Podfile:
    facebook_event (from `.symlinks/plugins/facebook_event/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      FBSDKCoreKit (~> 8.2.0)

    flutter_facebook_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`) was resolved to 3.5.3, which depends on
      FBSDKCoreKit (~> 12.1.0)

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:702:in `attempt_to_filter_existing_spec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:673:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
`

I tried to run the project but could not succeed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try installing a new version of ruby. Check [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

(duplicate of [Flutter: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKCoreKit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67283211/flutter-cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-fbsdkcorekit))

```
To fix this issue follow below steps:

flutter clean
Run rm -f ios/Podfile.lock (For remove ios/Podfile.lock file)
cd ios and hit pod update (Updates all the dependencies)
flutter run
```

(credit to Paresh Mangukiya)

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your project folder terminal

```
flutter clean && rm -f ios/Podfile.lock && flutter build ios
```

then run

```
flutter run
```